# Numerical difference between all rows within a group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) that looks a bit like

```
Indices<-data.frame("Animal"=c("Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Bird", 
                    "Bird"), "Trend"=c(1,3,5,-3,1,2,4,2,1), "Project"=c("ABC", "ABC2",
                    "EDF", "ABC", "EDF", "GHI", "ABC2", "ABC", "GHI"))
```

I want to find out whether two or more trend estimates differ by `>= 3` within each animal group. I tried  using `mutate` and `lag`:

```
    Indices %>%
      group_by(CommonName) %>%
      mutate(Diff = Trend - lag(Trend))
```

But this only shows me the difference between the rows that are right after each other, and I am trying to see the difference between all of the rows within a group. It also gives me the differences but doesn't tell me if the value is `>=3`.

I would prefer to have the end result being a list of the animals and project names that have an absolute trend difference `>=3`.

```
Animal     TrendDiff     Projects
Cat            4          ABC-EDF
Dog            7          ABC-ABC2
Dog            3          ABC2-EDF
Dog            4          ABC-EDF
Dog            5          ABC-GHI
```

I have well over 200 different "animal" groups and over 400 rows so need it to be something that doesn't need to specify each row. I am still very new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) so please be specific with your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to `left_join` your `Indices` data.frame with itself

```
library(dplyr)
Indices %>% 
      left_join(Indices, by = "Animal") %>%
      filter(Project.x != Project.y) %>%
      mutate(TrendDiff = Trend.x - Trend.y) %>% 
      filter(TrendDiff >= 3) 

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   Animal [2]
# Animal  Trend.x  Project.x Trend.y Project.y  TrendDiff
# cat          5   EDF             1 ABC               4
# Dog          1   EDF            -3 ABC               4
# Dog          2   GHI            -3 ABC               5
# Dog          4   ABC2           -3 ABC               7
# Dog          4   ABC2            1 EDF               3
```